# Implementaiton of rel="prev" and rel="next" inside a site code?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I searched a lot regarding my question, but I never found the exact piece of information explaning how to implement rel="prev" and rel="next" inside the code of a certain site?

I'll be very greatful if some could give me good imformation on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You add it to your head

```
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="prev" href="prev_page.html" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="current_page.html" />
    <link rel="next" href="next_page.html" />
</head>
```

Comment: Hi Martijn, I know that the tag go in the head of the document. Probably I didn't explained my question the best way. The site that I'm speaking is using custom made CMS build with PHP. So I want to undestand how to implement tham using PHP.

Comment: If your CMS is custom made, build a custom made function to see which is the prev/next and add that to your head ;)